# C homework with pipes and forks

Tags: c, pipe, fork

**Hello everyone,**

I'm quite lost in my school homework since they haven't told us much about it and I haven't done anything like that before.

**The task is:**

*In the C language create a program that creates two processes (fork function) and connects them via pipe (the pipe function).
The first descendant redirects its' stdout into the pipe and writes (space separated) pairs of random numbers into it (function rand).
Delay the output of the numbers (i.e. by 1 second).*

*The first descendant has 
to treat the SIGUSR1 signal (sigaction function) and in case of receiving such signal it prints a string “TERMINATED” to it's stderr and terminates.*

*The second descendant redirects the pipe output to it's stdin, redirects it's stdout into a file called out.txt in 
the current directory and executes a binary file (execl function) for finding the greatest common divisor (the output of our previous tasks where we had to write a makefile that runs a small C program that detects if a number is prime).*

*The parent process waits 5 seconds and then sends SIGUSR1 to the first process (number generator). This should perform a correct termination of both processes. It waits for the sub-processes to terminate (wait function) and terminates itself.*

*In fact you are implementing something like this: while : ; do echo $RANDOM $RANDOM ; sleep 1; done | ./c1_task > out.txt*

I'm absolutely lost in this and I have nothing so far unfortunatelly.
I don't know where to start.

Could somebody advise me something, please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This site is specifically for questions, not general advice or assistance.

Comment: If you're using a linux based OS, check out `man pipe`, `man fork`, etc.

Comment: Of course if you're using the `fork` function, I can safely assume that you're not programming on windows. :) (Yes, I know there's Cygwin...)

Comment: Does your class have a textbook or class notes that explain the concepts?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz ok sorry then, so is here any site for general advise or assistance?

Comment: @JefréN. your assumption is right.. I have checked 'man pipe' etc. already but it didn't help me much so that's probably why I came here..

Comment: @MarkPlotnick The class is more like individual work, they usually tell us maybe the basic things which I actually understand but I just don't know how to connect them or how to work with them to finish my hw.

Comment: Why don't you get a list of things you need to do: "Create two child processes with `fork`," "Connect them to a pipe," etc? Figure out what you need to use to accomplish the steps, and do some research on them?

Answer (score 2):

**Since I don't believe in doing people's work for them,** I can't give you the "solution." I can, however, show you some of the concepts that you need to know to fulfill your assignment. I can also give you a couple of links, but if you just search for help with the concepts you don't understand, you're likely to find the information you need anyways.

Now that I've delivered a paragraph of introductory information, I'm going to work you through some of the concepts you need to understand to solve this problem.
<sub>I may fill in some missing information if I get (and feel like it's worth spending) the time necessary to turn this into a pseudo-tutorial. :)</sub>

<sub>The information provided may be simplified, a little vague, or otherwise open to improvement. Feel free to let me know if you, dear reader, spot a problem.</sub>

---

**First Concept: fork()-ing**

*What is it?* `fork()` makes it easy to do multiple things simultaneously by duplicating (much of) the current process into another process. (Actually, it is similar to [asexual reproduction.](https://duckduckgo.com?q=asexual+reproduction))

For instance, the *child* process (this is the new process that was created by making the `fork()` system call) inherits open file descriptors (this is an important point!), has its own copy of variables that the parent process (has/had), etc.

*Example:* Here's an example program that illustrates a thing or two. Note the `wait()`. It makes the parent, the process that called `fork()`, wait to continue executing the rest of the program until a child has terminated. Without `wait(NULL)`, we can't guarantee that the parent's `printf` statement will run after the child's `printf` statement.

```
#include <stdio.h> //the usual, perror
#include <stdlib.h> //exit
#include <sys/types.h> //wait() / pid_t
#include <sys/wait.h> //wait()
#include <unistd.h> // fork()

int main () {
    pid_t cpid;

    //create our child.
    //fork() returns -1 if the fork failed, otherwise it returns
    //    the pid of the child to the parent,
    //    and 0 to the child
    cpid = fork();

    //Both the child process and parent process executed the
    //"cpid =" assignment.
    //However, they both modified their own version of cpid.
    //From now on, everything is run by both the child and parent.

    //the fork failed; there is no child so we're done.
    if (cpid < 0) {
        perror("During attempted fork");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

    //Though the if statement will be checked by both,
    //cpid will equal 0 only in the child process.
    if (cpid == 0) {
        //This will be executed by the child.
        printf("Hello. I'm your child.\n");

        //Now that we've let Pops know that we're alive...
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }

     else if (cpid > 0) {
        //wait for our child to terminate.
        //I dare you to comment this out & run the program a few times.
        //Does the parent ever print before the child?
        wait(NULL);

        printf("I proudly parented 1 child.\n");
        }

     return 0;
     }
```

*Other:* You can see another example [here.](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/ForkExecProcesses.html)

---

**Second concept: Pipes**

*What is a pipe?* A pipe is a method for interprocess communication. Basically, it has one end that data can be put in (`write()` is one way to do it) and one end that data can be gotten out of (using `read`).

Pipes are created using the `pipe()` system call. It returns -1 on error. It's only argument is the address of an array of two ints, which we'll call `pipe_fds`.

If the call succeeded, the first element in `pipe_fds` contains the `file descriptor` that is used to read from the pipe; the second element contains the `file descriptor` used to write to the pipe.

You can write to the pipe with `write()` and read from the pipe with `read()`. (More info about using pipes can be found at [various places](http://tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node11.html) on [the internet.](https://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~pxk/416/notes/c-tutorials/pipe.html)

Here's an example:

```
#include <stdio.h> //the usual, perror
#include <stdlib.h> //exit
#include <sys/types.h> //wait() / pid_t
#include <sys/wait.h> //wait()
#include <unistd.h> // fork(), pipe()

#define BUFLEN 256 //must be greater than one

int main () {
    int pipe_fds[2],
        pipe_ret;
    pid_t cpid;

    //Let's create a pipe.
    //Note that we do this *before* forking so that our forked child
    //    has access to the pipe's file descriptors, pipe_fds.
    pipe_ret = pipe(pipe_fds);

    //we couldn't create our pipe
    if (pipe_ret == -1) {
        perror("Pipe Creation");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

    //create our child.
    cpid = fork();

    //the fork failed; there is no child so we're done.
    if (cpid < 0) {
        perror("During attempted fork");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

    //Am I the child?
    if (cpid == 0) {
        //close the childs read end of the pipe.
        //Failing to close unused pipe ends is life or death!
        //(Check `man 7 pipe`)
        close(pipe_fds[0]);

        //Send a message through the pipe.
        //NOTE: For simplicity's sake, we assume that our printing works.
        //    In the real world, it might not write everything, etc.
        //We could use `write()`, but this way is easier.
        dprintf(pipe_fds[1], "Daddy, I'm alive.\n");

        //We're done writing. Close write end of the pipe.
        //This is the wise thing to do, but it would get closed anyways.
        close(pipe_fds[1]);

        //Now that we've let Pops know that we're alive...
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }

     else if (cpid > 0) {
        char buf[BUFLEN] = {};
        int bytes_read = 0;

        //close *our* write end of the pipe. Important!
        //Comment this out and watch your program hang.
        //Again, check out `man 7 pipe`.
        close(pipe_fds[1]);

        //read data from pipe until we reach EOF
        while ((bytes_read = read(pipe_fds[0], buf, BUFLEN - 1)) > 0) {
            //null terminate our string.
            //(We could use snprintf instead...)
            buf[bytes_read] = '\0';

            //You can comment this out to prove to yourself that
            //we're the one printing the child's message.
            printf("%s", buf);
            }

        //close read end of pipe
        close(pipe_fds[0]);

        //wait for our child to terminate.
        wait(NULL);

        printf("I proudly parented 1 child.\n");
        }

     return 0;
     }
```

---

**As you can see,** I just gave a small tutorial on two of the concepts you need to know to finish your assignment. I need some sleep, so I'll leave it at that for tonight.

Read and experiment with the examples! Notes in the comments are to help you learn.

Comment: Thanks for this answer man, helped alot. I have finished my homework already, now it everything gives sense and I find it quite easy and logic :D
If anyone would see the code, here is the final, fully working version http://pastebin.com/tgGNf3Fb  (c1task is another program that reads lines from stdin until EOF (each line contains two natural numbers separated by space) and finds (writes in stdout) biggest common divider of those two numbers or writes string "prime" on stdout if BOTH numbers are prime).

Comment: @hofiisek: I'm glad it worked out for you... (Hope you get a good grade. :D)

Comment: hehe, thanks..:) but I don't care much about grades, especially not in this class.. passing is passing :D

Comment: @hofiisek: What class is it? (My curiosity is peaked. How could anyone not want to get a great grade in computer ... :D) By the way, is it possible to accept this answer ... ?

Comment: Its an english version of Operating systems and network (English version means easier but we have to take at least one english educated class anyway).. (maybe you think its a highscool homework, so not, its an  university homework :D ) and I dont really see big difference between getting C or D/E from a subject Im not intrested in so much :D
btw. answer accepted (I hope)

Comment: @hofiisek: Thanks for the explanation and your *attempt* to accept the answer. Have a good one. :)